# VBScript not running depending on the web server

Tags: vbscript, iis-7, automation, iis-7.5

I've a very strange problem with a VBScript: it works fine depending on the server where the web is located.

I have the same web application on two servers with IIS 7.5. In each server, the code is **exactly** the same.

The VBScript executes some Excel lines and it updates some information at the web application. The problem comes when updating this information. In one of the servers, there's no problem, but in the other, I get the error below:

[image: Error running the script]

**As the script runs as it would do, I guess there's no syntax error**

The code throwing the error is:

```
With objIE
    If (testing) Then
        .Navigate URLtesting
    Else
        .Navigate URL
        WScript.Sleep 2000
    End If

    WaitWebLoad()
    .document.getElementById(user).Value = userScript
    .document.getElementById(password).Value = passwordScript
    .document.getElementById(logInButton).Click()
    WaitWebLoad()
    .document.getElementByID(loretoLink).Click()
    WaitWebLoad()
    .document.getElementByID(updatePLLink).Click()
    WaitWebLoad()

    Do
        lastRow = activeSheet.Cells(rowIndex, columnPL_ID).Value
        dateAssociated = activeSheet.Cells(rowIndex, columnArrivalDate).Value
        concesion = activeSheet.Cells(rowIndex, columnConcesion).Value
        If lastRow <> "" Then
            .document.getElementByID(searchPL_TB).Value = lastRow
            .document.getElementByID(searchPL_Button).Click()
            WaitWebLoad()
            If (Not (.document.getElementByID(errorLookingPL)) Is Nothing Or Not (.document.getElementByID(noSearchResult) Is Nothing)) Then
                'PL not found
                recordsNotFound = recordsNotFound + 1
                WriteOpenFileText(logFilePath), (Now & vbTab & "***PL not found: " & lastRow & " - [" & dateAssociated & "]" & " - " & concesion & vbCrLf)
            Else ...
```

The line number 295 is:

```
If (Not (.document.getElementByID(errorLookingPL)) is Nothing Or Not (.document.getElementByID(noSearchResult) is Nothing)) Then
```

The WaitWebLoad function code is:

```
Function WaitWebLoad()
    Dim timer
    timer = 0

    With objIE
        Do While .Busy
            If timer < timerWebLoad Then
                WScript.Sleep 100
                timer = 100
            Else
                'Error loading the web
                objExcel.Workbooks.close
                objExcel.quit
                objIE.quit
                DeleteFile(pathTemp)
                endScriptStamp = Now

                WScript.Echo("Error." & vbCrLf & "Total runtime is: " & DateDiff("s", startScriptStamp, endScriptStamp) & " seconds.")
                WScript.quit
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Function
```

I guess the problem is that the script, when running the server where the error takes place, is losing the `objIE` object, but I don't know why it's becoming lost only in one of the servers.

Comment: I'm not sure what IIS has to do with this, your running VBS code which is client-side *(the server in this instance being the client)*, it has no bearing on IIS as far as I can see??

Comment: It's likely that one of the servers doesn't have Excel installed or the COM components at least. Either way you need to do some debugging to work out which object is not set.

Comment: @Lankymart It's correct. The server has nothing to do with this: the script is like a person doing some actions in a web application. But, depending on the server I access the web app, it works fine or not. The server does not need to have Excel installed or the COM components, because if I access the web located in the server where the script running throws the error, the web app is completely useful by human interaction.

Comment: What?!? Sorry but I lost you at *"The server does not need to have Excel installed or the COM components, because if I access the web located in the server where the script running throws the error, the web app is completely useful by human interaction"*...

Comment: Might be a difference in `iis-7` vs. `iis-7.5` or in `IIS` _settings_? Sorry, I'm not too good in `IIS` topic; you could ask at SuperUser with link to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37563820/3439404).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getElementById` method returns the first **object** with the same `ID` attribute as the specified value, or **null** if the `id` cannot be found. Reference:  [.NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Document Object Model (DOM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx).
On the other side, [`Is` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ake1y5wx(v=vs.84).aspx) compares two **object** reference variables and `Null` is not an object; it indicates that a variable contains no valid data.
Moreover, if used in [VBScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt(v=vs.84).aspx), `getElementById` method could raise `800A01A8` (=decimal `-2146827864`) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: `Object required` if used improperly: for instance, as you can't write `Set objAny = Null`!

Here's a workaround:

```
On Error Resume Next                                              ' enable error handling
  Set oerrorLookingPL = .document.getElementByID(errorLookingPL)  ' try
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set oerrorLookingPL = Nothing           ' an error occurred?
  Err.Clear
  If Vartype(oerrorLookingPL) = 1 Then Set oerrorLookingPL = Nothing   ' Null => Nothing
  Set onoSearchResult = .document.getElementByID(noSearchResult)
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set onoSearchResult = Nothing
  Err.Clear
  If Vartype(onoSearchResult) = 1 Then Set onoSearchResult = Nothing
On Error Goto 0                                                   ' disable error handling
If (Not (oerrorLookingPL Is Nothing) Or Not (onoSearchResult Is Nothing)) Then
```

I can't recommend global use of `On Error Resume Next` as `If condition Then …` statement always evaluates given `condition` to `True` if a runtime error occurs while evaluating it, see next example:

```
On Error Resume Next
' show Variant subtype information about Null and Nothing
Wscript.Echo VarType(Null)    & " Null    " & TypeName(Null)
Wscript.Echo VarType(Nothing) & " Nothing " & TypeName(Nothing)
' all conditions as well as their negations are evaluated to `True`
if     (Null  = Nothing) then Wscript.Echo "     Null  = Nothing"
if NOT (Null  = Nothing) then Wscript.Echo "not (Null  = Nothing)"
if     (Null is Nothing) then Wscript.Echo "     Null is Nothing"
if NOT (Null is Nothing) then Wscript.Echo "not (Null is Nothing)"
' show runtime error
On Error GoTo 0
if     (Null is Nothing) then Wscript.Echo "     Null is Nothing"
```

Both `Null = Nothing` and `Null is Nothing` conditions are evaluated to `True` as well as their negations!

```
==> cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\37563820.vbs
1 Null    Null
9 Nothing Nothing
     Null  = Nothing
not (Null  = Nothing)
     Null is Nothing
NOT (Null is Nothing)
==> D:\VB_scripts\SO\37563820.vbs(12, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required
```

Comment: Why the reference to .Net methods? Also where in the OPs code have they even tried to compare `Null`? I'm not entirely sure what you are getting at with the question. Missing object references are usually due to dependencies *(COM etc.)* that are not set in the environment. The OP even says it works on one and not the other. So what's the point of this?

Comment: @Lankymart _where in the OPs code have they even tried to compare `Null`?_ Whichever `.document.getElementByID(…)` in the line number 295 _must_ return `Null`: note that my last  code snippet shows exactly the same error. On the other hand,  the foremost one could show a way how to  begin with your hint: _Either way you need to do some debugging to work out which object is not set_.

Comment: It works!! But I don't understand why my original code works with the page located in one of the servers and not in the other one...

Comment: @Carlos are you _sure_ that the page is the same on all servers? And what about MSIE version? Client-side `VBScript` is considered outdated and deprecated nowadays, and might not work in any modern browser including newer versions of MSIE.

Comment: @JosefZ yes, I'm sure the page is the same 'cause I've done copy-paste. The script is running in the same computer, so the MSIE version is the same. The only difference between the 2 web pages is the server where they 're located...